# Leslie Jones' punch line from SNL

Tags: jokes

In this episode of SNL, Leslie Jones is saying something as a closing punch line.

It's supposed to be funny, and this is how I dictate.

" I tell it like T.O.s. "

But I doubt it's correct. Does anybody know what she says?

[The link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_WqYtj1Wik)

Comment: *"I tell it like a T.O."* Is that a **tick-off**? Seeing as she just laid it on the line? I can't comment on the humour since it seems to be regional/topical.

Comment: I tell it like a teos: a teo is basically a very masculine man (Urban Dictionary).However, it may be purposely mispronounced for: tell it like it tis, which came out tee-os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context: A man quit his job to pursue a singing career. He invites his friends to listen to his song. It’s awful, but the friends only make positive comments. Then Leslie bursts in, says it’s awful, and says that if the friends say otherwise, then they are not being honest. Then she says the line.

In “standard” English, she is saying *I tell it like it is*:

> [tell it like it is](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tell+it+like+it+is)
>   To speak bluntly, directly, and truthfully, even if what is being said is undesirable to the listener.
>   *I always respect employees who are willing to tell it like it is, rather than trying to sugarcoat everything to save a little face.*
>   *I tell it like it is, and that rubs a lot of people the wrong way.* 
>   (TFD)

However, she’s pronouncing “it is” in a non-standard way for comedic effect. It does sound kind of like “it-T.O.s”. My speculation is that she was trying to mimic, mock, or exaggerate a real-world dialect.

Comment: She clearly says: like **a** "teeos". If it were like it tis, there would be no **a**.

Comment: It sounds like “iteeos”, _i_ like in _it_, to me. I don’t really hear an _a_.

Comment: Thank you very much!!